# Why does an alias with a 'having' clause not exist in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-performance, postgresql-9.6, column-alias

I am trying to calculate distance between two coordinates and fetching some information based on a few conditions. A similar query with the 'having' clause was working in MySQL. But why is it not working in PostgreSQL?

This is my query:

```
    SELECT *, ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude1 ) ) *
    cos( radians( longitude1 ) - radians(longitude) ) + sin( radians(latitude) ) *
    sin( radians( latitude1 ) ) ) ) AS distance from table WHERE
    verified=true AND best_for LIKE '%xyz%' AND uuid NOT IN (SELECT uuid::uuid FROM table2 WHERE
    from_date BETWEEN '2020-12-17 06:30'::date AND '2020-12-18 12:30'::date AND
    to_date BETWEEN '2020-12-17 06:30'::date AND '2020-12-18 12:30'::date  AND )
    HAVING distance < 50 ORDER BY distance
```

Why does distance not exist? And how can I modify this query to make it work in PostgreSQL?

Comment: I hope your table is small.  The current formulation cannot use indexes, so it will do a full table scan.  http://mysql.rjweb.org/doc.php/find_nearest_in_mysql

Comment: you can use geometrical functions like https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/270906/mysql-insert-into-select-vs-bulk-inserts-performance

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That's the rule the SQL standard sets (and MySQL ignores some of the rules the standard defines and allows invalid SQL).

You can't use a column alias on the same level where you defined it and `having` is only allowed in a query that uses aggregation. If you want to avoid repeating the expression, use a derived table.

It's also typically faster to use `NOT EXISTS` instead of `NOT IN`

```
SELECT *
FROM (
  SELECT *, 
        ( 6371 * acos( cos( radians(latitude) ) * cos( radians( latitude1 ) ) * 
          cos( radians( longitude1 ) - radians(longitude) ) + sin( radians(latitude) ) * 
          sin( radians( latitude1 ) ) ) ) AS distance 
  from table t1
  WHERE verified = true 
    AND best_for LIKE '%xyz%' 
    AND NOT EXISTS (SELECT *
                     FROM table2 t2
                     WHERE t2.from_date BETWEEN '2020-12-17 06:30'::date AND '2020-12-18 12:30'::date 
                       AND t2.to_date BETWEEN '2020-12-17 06:30'::date AND '2020-12-18 12:30'::date  
                       AND t2.uuid::uuid = t1.uuid)
) x                       
WHERE distance < 50 
ORDER BY distance
```

Comment: Sorry, but having *is* allowed without a `group by`! For example, `select max(id) from table having max(id) < 100000;` Using `where` won't work in this case because you're not allowed to use the aggregate in the where clause.

Comment: @Colin'tHart: you are right, I should have written "without aggregation".

Comment: there is a typo `EXISTS` not `EXSIST`